# Trying to get the x, y coordinate of each random circle that is drawn in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ontouch

I am making a game that will create random circles on the screen. The circles created randomly will have the value red or green.

My question is that I would like to be able to not only determine when a user clicks on one of the circles but determine what circle they have ultimately clicked on (red or green).
My main problem is trying to find the x and y of the circle that will be drawn.

Here is my code:

```
    public class DrawingView extends View {



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };



    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        // code below works when its here 

        float randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
        float randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = event.getX();
   int y = event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y)){
      //Do your things here
   }
   return true;
}

private boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if (((x - randomWidth)^2 + (y - randomHeight)^2) < radius^2)
    return true;
  return false;    
}



}
```

code below does not work

```
public class DrawingView extends View {



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    //its right below here the code compiles perfectly, but gets errors in logcat
    int randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
    int randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };



    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y)){
      //Do your things here
   }
   return true;
}

private boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if (((x - randomWidth)^2 + (y - randomHeight)^2) < radius^2)
    return true;
  return false;    
}



}
```

here is the logcat

```
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010): Process: com.Tripps.thesimplegame, PID: 4010
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Tripps.thesimplegame/com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at com.Tripps.thesimplegame.DrawingView.<init>(DrawingView.java:38)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at com.Tripps.thesimplegame.Main.onCreate(Main.java:30)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-01 03:41:48.856: E/AndroidRuntime(4010):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling `randomWidth` and `randomheight` actually are the x and y cordinates of your circle. 
    this is the methods sign:

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

To check if the user clicked inside the circle you can do this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int)event.getX();
   int y = (int)event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y)){
      //Do your things here
   }
   return true;
}

private boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if (((x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2) < radius^2)
    return true;
  return false;    
}
```

Comment: @DevinTripp Random.nextInt(int n) accepts an integer as value you can not pass float or others.

Comment: no its with any data type

Comment: have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)
It accepts only a int if you cal Random.nextInt(int n)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74243/discussion-between-devin-tripp-and-assa).