# check whether there is a circle at a point where user has touched

Tags: android, opencv

I have a code where some circles are drawn automatically after passing the image to a function an some are drawn manually using drawcircle().  Now, I want to see that when the user touches a point, if there is already a circle there, then hide/remove it. 
[image]

Any leads please?

Comment: and you dont know how to check if some point (x, y) is inside some circle (cx, cy, radius)?

Comment: I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385506/trying-to-get-the-x-y-coordinate-of-each-random-circle-that-is-drawn-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1). In the accepted answer, what is center_x, center_y? And the thing is, that on touching the point where a circle is not drawn,  drawCircle is called. And isInsideCircle(x,y) returns true.

Comment: Sorry, please check.

Comment: check what? do you know how to check if some point (x, y) is inside some circle (cx, cy, radius) or not?

Comment: No, Please tell.

Comment: `Math.hypot(x - cx, y - cy) < radius`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151861/discussion-between-harshita-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

If all circle are drown by you by draw circle . Then store the coordinates of all circles in a list and on then check the the clicked position by Region . If region contains the coordinate then click is inside the circle otherwise its outside somewhere on Canvas.Below is an example it returns the index of clicked circle .

```
 private int findPointAt(int x, int y) {
   if(dotsList!=null) {
       if (dotsList.isEmpty()) {
           return -1;
       }
       final int width = circleRadius * 2;
       final Region r = new Region();
       for (int i = 0; i < dotsList.size(); i++) {
           final int pointX = dotsList.get(i).x;
           final int pointY = dotsList.get(i).y;
           r.set(pointX - width, pointY - width, pointX + width, pointY + width);
           if (r.contains(x, y)) {
               selectedPosition = i;
               return i;
           }
       }
   }
   return -1;
```

}

if returns -1 then click is outside otherwise index of circle is returned .

Comment: Hey, thanks for help. I'll try this. This would serve the purpose for the ones I draw myself. In the picture I've shared, the darker circle is drawn on touch while others are drawn automatically through a function. Any leads on that. i was thinking, if I could get the position of that point, I could draw a circle of same colour as the background.

Comment: Since all circle are drawn at runtime on canvas just store the cx and Cy in a list of PointF(List<PointF>) (radius is constant i think ) .Then check if they reside in the circle or outside.

Comment: How to get the dotsList?